# Como generar un programa que genere un código de usuario c#?

Tags: c#, array, .net, consola

Tengo una tarea de colegio, la cual dicta así: 
Escribir un programa que sirva para generar códigos de usuario por el procedimiento siguiente: Tiene que leer el nombre y los 2 apellidos de una persona y devolver un código de usuario formado por las 3 primeras letras del primer apellido, las tres primeras letras del segundo apellido y las 3 primeras letras del nombre. Por ejemplo, si la cadena de entrada es: "JORDI GUINOVART SANTS" debe devolver "GUISANJOR.

Tengo un programa similar a este que se me pide

```
        string nombre, Ap, Am;
        DateTime fechaNac;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString());
        Console.Write("Nombre:              ");
        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Apellido paterno:     ");
        Ap = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Apellido materno:     ");
        Am = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Fecha Nacimiento:     ");
        fechaNac = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("RFC : {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", Ap[0], Ap[1], Am[0], 
        Am[0], nombre[0], fechaNac.ToString("yyMMdd"));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Sin embargo, este programa debo emplear un ciclo al momento de ingresar los datos, alguna idea en particular de como generarlo de esa forma? me seria muy útil de su ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano...

Comment: A que se refiere con un ciclo al momento  de ingresar los datos? Donde tiene que ingresarlos en una bd, un archivo o que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Substring(inicio, fin)

Inicio es de donde quieras comenzar a extraer de la cadena.
Fin es hasta donde quieres extraer.

Lo único que recomendaría seria validar el tamaño de la cadena, ya que se puede producir alguna excepción al momento de extraer algo fuera de los limites de alguna palabra.

Un ejemplo aquí

```
String nombre = "Luis", apellido = "Benitez", apellido2 = "Alvarado";
            if(nombre.Length >=3 && apellido.Length >= 3 && apellido2.Length >= 3)
            {
                String concatenado = nombre.Substring(0, 3) + apellido.Substring(0, 3) + apellido2.Substring(0, 3);
                Console.WriteLine(concatenado);

            }
```

OutPut

```
LuiBenAlv
```

Answer (score 0):

De cada cadena, puedes sacar los caracteres que quieras con el metodo substring, el primer parametro es la posicion desde donde comienzas y el segundo parametro la cantidad de caracteres que quieres extraer.

```
string resultado = apellido1.Substring(0, 3);
```